How to solve error: 500 - when trying to set New Default Branch - Azure Devops Repos
** AFTER 48 hours Problem disappeared **
When trying to set default branch i get the following error
I get error 500 see image.

No details are given to this error - and i could not find any other questions regarding this problem.
On other repositories on the same project i don't see this problem.
I have checked my permissions:


Check on another repository on the same project.
Check i have permission.

On your web browser, you can open the "Developer tools" via pressing F12, then do the "Change default branch" action again. Then go to 'Console' and 'Network' tabs on the "Developer tools", try to check if you can get more detailed error messages/logs for the 500 error.

problem disappeared

Had  you made any change in the repository to let the issue disappear? If so, maybe, you can post an answer for it. This could be also helpful for other users who have the similar issues.

no change, after 48 hours problem disappeard

That's good. Maybe, the problem is caused by a temporary server issue.

The problem might be caused by a temporary server issue. The state code 500 generally is with the Internal Server Error.
Since the temporary server issue had been mitigated, the problem got disappeared.
